# A doubt about line integral as a manifold.

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, smooth-manifolds

I'm trying do a conection between a definition that I've learned in my graduation and nowadays a definition that I've learned in my doctorate studies.

> **Calculus Definition:**
>
> Let $C$ be a curve in $\Bbb{R}^n$ and $r:I\to\Bbb{R}^n$ a parametrization for it, let $f:C\to\Bbb{R}$ a continuous function, then the line integral of $f$ over $C$ is defined by
>   $$\int_Cf\,ds=\int_I(f\circ r)(t)\,|r'(t)|dt.\qquad(1)$$
>
> **Manifold definition:**
>
> Let $M$ be a (compact) smooth manifold, let $\phi:U\subset\Bbb{R}^n\to \phi(U)\subset M$ a local defining function (maybe inverse of a chart map), let $\omega$ a $n$-form on $M$ (with compact support in $\phi(U)$), then
>   $$\int_M\omega=\int_U\phi^*\omega,\qquad(2)$$
>   where $\phi^*$ is the pullback map.

I want to know how to prove $(1)$ using $(2)$, I mean, consider $M=C$, $\phi=r$ and $\omega=f\,ds$, how can I obtain $(1)$?

Sugestions, commets and answers will useful, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We define the integral by $(2)$, let $C\in\mathbb{R}^n$ be a smooth curve parametrized by $r$, and let $f:C\to\mathbb{R}$. In order to use $(2)$ we need to define a $1$-form $\omega$ on $C$. We take the orientation induced by $r$, and then for $p\in C$ and a positive $v\in T_pC$ we set $\omega(v)=f(p)\cdot|v|$. It follows immediately that the pullback is given by $$r^*\omega=f\circ r(t)\cdot|r'(t)|dt,$$
and we're done.

Comment: When you say "a positive $v\in T_pC$", what does this mean?

Comment: It means positive WRT the induced orientation by $r$. On $I$ there is a standard orientation, and for any $p\in C$ we have an isomorphism $dr:T_{r^{-1}(p)}I\to T_pC$, so a tangent vector at $p$ is positive if it is the image of a positive tangent vector at $r^{-1}(p)$.

Comment: I got it! I think a similar argumentation solves the problem with a surface integral, thanks for your answer.

Comment: Your thought is correct. When the dimension is greater than $1$, one defines a volume form by giving a positive orthonormal basis the value $1$.